# InputFormatWrapper can not support RecordReaders

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-emr

Running a simple hive query on Amazon EMR

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLENAME`,

on "any" external table, gives the following error

> InputFormatWrapper can not support RecordReaders that don't return
>   same key & value objects. current reader class : class
>   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.db.MySQLDBRecordReader

On running `set mapred.map.tasks=1;` 
the above error gets resolved, but it still persists for the View.

The tasks run fine if I remove Tez as hive execution engine
`set hive.execution.engine=mr;`

Used Qubole and MysqlJdbcConnector Jars to connect the external database..

Sample External Table

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `TEST` (
  `TEST_ID` int   ,
  `TEST` int  ,
  `STATE` string  ,
  `CITY` string  ,
  `CITY_TYPE` string,
  `INTERNAL_TAT` int  ,
  `LP_COMMIT_TAT` int  ) STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.storagehandler.JdbcStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES (  "mapred.jdbc.driver.class"="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",  "mapred.jdbc.url"="jdbc:mysql://TEST_URL",  "mapred.jdbc.username"="USERNAME",  "mapred.jdbc.input.table.name"="TEST",  "mapred.jdbc.output.table.name" = "TEST",  "mapred.jdbc.hive.lazy.split"= "true","mapred.jdbc.password"="PASSWORD");
```

Couldn't find anything related online. The same question is unanswered at many other places

- https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/65136/problems-with-apache-kylin-and-hive-jdbc-storage-h.html
- [Problems with Apache Kylin and Hive-JDBC-Storage-Handler when build Cube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40419387/problems-with-apache-kylin-and-hive-jdbc-storage-handler-when-build-cube)

Comment: till there is no table describe   use   describe extended <tablename>   this issue is more likely to your file..

Comment: @sandeeprawat can you please elaborate? What do you mean?

Comment: hi if we do not know what is the table structure  it will be tough to understand what  or how it is workig

Comment: Check the edited question now.